# Display different images than original when listview scrolled

Tags: android

I am facing a big problem in listview.
The problem is that when I click on button I get all offer detail. And I am showing that detail in listview. Listview contain image also that load image from server. It load data properly,
but the problem is that when I scroll my listview images will change as I scrolled list.

Here is my code

```
public class Offer_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;

String[] offer_title;
String[] offerimg1;
String[] mrp;
String[] offerprice;
String[] you_save;
 String[] imgURLArray;
Bitmap bitmap;
ImageView offerimg;
int a;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public Offer_adapter(Activity a, String[] offer_title, String[] offerimg1, String[] mrp, String[] you_save, String[] offerprice,String[] imgURLArray) {
    activity = a;
    this.offer_title = offer_title;
    this.offerimg1 = offerimg1;
    this.mrp = mrp;
    this.offerprice = offerprice;
    this.you_save = you_save;
    this.imgURLArray = imgURLArray;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.
            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mrp.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {

    public TextView offertitle;
    public TextView offermrp;
    public TextView offersave;
    public TextView ofrprice;
    public ImageView offerimg;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

         //imgURLArray[position] = "http://www.surun.co/preost/mod_offer/images/" + offerimg1[position];

        /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_list, null);

        /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.offertitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ofrtitle);
        holder.offermrp = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.offeroriginal);
        offerimg = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ofr_img);
        holder.offersave = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.saveoffer);
        holder.ofrprice = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.priceoffer);
        /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
        vi.setTag(holder);

    holder.offertitle.setText(offer_title[position]);
    holder.offermrp.setPaintFlags(holder.offermrp.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    holder.offermrp.setText("Original Price : \u20B9" + mrp[position]);
    holder.offersave.setText("You Save : \u20B9"+you_save[position]);
    holder.ofrprice.setText("Offer Price : \u20B9"+offerprice[position]);

   // ImageView image = holder.offerimg;
    //if (holder.offerimg != null) {
     //   new ImageDownloaderTask(image).execute(imgURLArray[position]);

   // }

    Glide.with(activity).load(imgURLArray[position]).placeholder(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loadingoffer)).error(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loadingoffer)).into(offerimg);

    return vi;
}
```

And the data which I got from server I get it as

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.v(TAG, "In onPreExecute of the loading offers page.");
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UserLogedIn.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mp3));
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", u_id));
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();


        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(URLOFFER, ServiceHandler.POST, param);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null)

        {
            try {

                contacts1 = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                lengthofaffer = contacts1.length();
                Log.v(TAG, ".................." + lengthofaffer);

                if (lengthofaffer > 0) {
                    offer_title = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    imgURLArray=new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offer_expiry = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    available_city = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    mrp = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerprice = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    you_save = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    product_detail = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    key_feature = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    cod = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    emi = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    moneyback = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    delivery = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    terms = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerimg1 = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerimg2 = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerimg3 = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerimg4 = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    offerimg5 = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    date = new String[contacts1.length()];
                    for (int i = (lengthofaffer - 1), j = 0; i >= 0 && j < contacts1.length(); i--, j++)
                    {// for (int i = 0; i < contacts1.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = contacts1.getJSONObject(i);

                        Log.v(TAG, "" + i);
                        String offer_title1 = c.getString(TAG_offer_title);
                        String offer_expiry1 = c.getString(TAG_offer_expiry);
                        String available_city1 = c.getString(TAG_available_city);
                        String mrp1 = c.getString(TAG_mrp);
                        String offerprice1 = c.getString(TAG_offerprice);
                        String you_save1 = c.getString(TAG_you_save);
                        String product_detail1 = c.getString(TAG_product_detail);
                        String key_feature1 = c.getString(TAG_key_feature);
                        String cod1 = c.getString(TAG_cod);
                        String emi1 = c.getString(TAG_emi);
                        String moneyback1 = c.getString(TAG_moneyback);
                        String delivery1 = c.getString(TAG_delivery);
                        String terms1 = c.getString(TAG_terms);
                        String offerimg11 = c.getString(TAG_offerimg1);
                        String offerimg21 = c.getString(TAG_offerimg2);
                        String offerimg31 = c.getString(TAG_offerimg3);
                        String offerimg41 = c.getString(TAG_offerimg4);
                        String offerimg51 = c.getString(TAG_offerimg5);
                        String date1 = c.getString(TAG_date);

                        offer_title[i] = offer_title1;
                        offer_expiry[i] = offer_expiry1;
                        available_city[i] = available_city1;
                        mrp[i] = mrp1;
                        offerprice[i] = offerprice1;
                        you_save[i] = you_save1;
                        product_detail[i] = product_detail1;
                        key_feature[i] = key_feature1;
                        cod[i] = cod1;
                        emi[i] = emi1;
                        moneyback[i] = moneyback1;
                        delivery[i] = delivery1;
                        terms[i] = terms1;
                        offerimg1[i] = offerimg11;
                        offerimg2[i] = offerimg21;
                        offerimg3[i] = offerimg31;
                        offerimg4[i] = offerimg41;
                        offerimg5[i] = offerimg51;
                        date[i] = date1;

                        imgURLArray[i] = "http://www.surun.co/preost/mod_offer/images/" + offerimg1[i];
                        Log.v(TAG,""+imgURLArray[i]);

                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.print("hiiiiiiiiiiii");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Log.v(TAG, "length of aaaaa" + lengthofaffer);
        if ( offer_title!= null && offer_title.length > 0) {
            Log.v(TAG,"abhijit");
           Offer_adapter adapter = new Offer_adapter(UserLogedIn.this, offer_title,offerimg1,mrp,you_save,offerprice,imgURLArray);
            offerlist.setAdapter(adapter);
            //offerlist.getSelectedView().setBackgroundColor();
            offerlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Intent ii = new Intent(UserLogedIn.this, Single_offer.class);
                    ii.putExtra("offer_title", offer_title[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offer_expiry", offer_expiry[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("available_city", available_city[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("mrp", mrp[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("cod", cod[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("emi", emi[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offer_price", offerprice[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("you_save", you_save[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("product_detail", product_detail[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("key_feature", key_feature[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("moneyback", moneyback[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("delivery", delivery[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("terms", terms[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("date", date[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offerimg1", offerimg1[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offerimg2", offerimg2[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offerimg3", offerimg3[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offerimg4", offerimg4[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("offerimg5", offerimg5[i]);
                    ii.putExtra("userid",u_id);
                    startActivity(ii);



                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserLogedIn.this);
            builder.setTitle("Alert");
            // builder.setIcon(R.drawable.unverified).show();
            builder.setMessage("No Offer Present");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            UserLogedIn.this.runOnUiThread(new java.lang.Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //show AlertDialog
                    alert.show();
                }
            });
        }
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog.hide();
    }//End of Inner class Load image
}
```

Comment: are you missing: holder.offerimg.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

Comment: i have edited my question

Comment: that code was wrong i mean that code is not required

Comment: please do check my edited answer!.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your adapter is not configured probably. Try this below:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (vi == null) {
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offer_list, parent,false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.offertitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ofrtitle);
        holder.offermrp = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.offeroriginal);
        holder.offerimg = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.ofr_img);
        holder.offersave = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.saveoffer);
        holder.ofrprice = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.priceoffer);
        vi.setTag(holder);


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
    }

    holder.offertitle.setText(offer_title[position]);
    holder.offermrp.setPaintFlags(holder.offermrp.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
    holder.offermrp.setText("Original Price : \u20B9" + mrp[position]);
    holder.offersave.setText("You Save : \u20B9" + you_save[position]);
    holder.ofrprice.setText("Offer Price : \u20B9" + offerprice[position]);
    Glide.with(activity).load(imgURLArray[position]).placeholder(activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loadingoffer)).error(activity
            .getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.loadingoffer)).into(holder.offerimg);

    return vi;
}
```

For more info, please refer to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: then you should accept the answer so others can benefit from it.